# EasyMock - how to mock private object instantiation and variable

Tags: java, swing, junit, mocking, easymock

I have the following class to test with mocking private object creations,

```
    class TestClass {

    private Dialog dialog;

    private DialogChangeListener listener = new DialogChangeListener() {
        public void onChange(Event e) {
            String v = e.getValue();
            if (condition1) {
                // perform operation 1
            } else if (condition2) {
                // perform operation 2
            } else if (condition3) {
               // perform operation 3
            }
        }
    }

    public void openDialog() {
        if (condition1) {
            dialog = new Dialog(arg1, arg2, listener);
        } else if (condition2) {
            dialog = new Dialog(arg1, arg2, arg3, listener);
        } else if (condition3) {
            dialog = new Dialog(arg1, arg2, arg3, listener);
        }
    }
}
```

In the above scenario, how to mock using EasyMock the private 'Dialog' variable and it's instantiations along with the private 'listener' variable, so that the rest of the operations are continued on a conditional basis.

Answer (score 0):

There are three parts to my answer.

First, you can't mock attributes and instantiation with EasyMock. These cases are rarely needed and mean you should refactor.

Second, PowerMock can mock instantiations. It is powerful but I actually never use it myself.

Third, in your case,

1. I would add a constructor taking the listener in parameter. To easily mocking it
2. Do a partial mock and extract the Dialog creation into a specific method. This is if you really need to keep the creation there. Otherwise, I would just move it to some factory and mock it.

Code example:

```
public void openDialog() {
    if (condition1) {
        dialog = createDialog(listener, arg1, arg2);
    } else if (condition2) {
        dialog = createDialog(listener, arg1, arg2, arg3);
    } else if (condition3) {
        dialog = createDialog(listener, arg1, arg2, arg3);
    }
}

/* default scope to make it mockable */ Dialog createDialog(DialogChangeListener listener, Object... args) {
    //...
}
```

And then the test:

```
TestClass testClass = EasyMock.partialMockBuilder(TestClass.class)
        .addMockedMethod("createDialog")
        .createMock();
expect(testClass.createDialog(listener, ...)).andReturn(someDialog);
```